# Removing tick line in recharts react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, recharts

i'm trying to remove the light gray line that's next to the darker gray line:
[image]

After searching the rechart library through and through i decided to try and hide it with a css file.

this is the code :

```
.recharts-layer.recharts-cartesian-axis-tick line{
display: hidden;
}
```

I've also tried :

```
.recharts-cartesian-axis-tick-line{
    display:hidden !important;
}
```

and still doesn't work.

it's important to note that the css file is linked and when trying to style something else it works.

this is what i see when i inspect and pick the element in the dev tools :
[image]

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is remove the `tickLine` from `YAxis`.

Something like that:

```js
<LineChart>
   ...
   <YAxis tickLine={false} />
   ...
</LineChart>
```

You can check more about it in [docs](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#tickLine) API.